# Line Chart for .NET prior framework 3.5

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mschart

I am developing an application and I must do it in WPF and use .NET 3.5. The problem is that I can't use MSCharts for 3.5 because that would require XP installations to install SP3, something that they don't want.

The WPF toolkit was buggy on their machines, so is there any other solution or I should start just drawing lines?

Comment: You mean this? http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyId=130F7986-BF49-4FE5-9CA8-910AE6EA442C&displaylang=en I can't imagine why that would require SP3 - does it really not install on SP2? If you force it to install on SP2 does it really not work?

Comment: Supported Operating Systems:Windows Server 2003 Service Pack 2;Windows Server 2008;Windows Vista;Windows XP Service Pack 3
I dont know why,it says that..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that Charts work with framework 3.5 -no 3.5 SP1 great... they work even with 3.0
I have SP3 windows versions on my old machines so i cant unistall SP3 to check.. but prior <3.5 doesnt require XP sp3.. so thats should be ok...